# Params Для Func<> или как?

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf, list, arraylist

Нужен List c Функциями. Реализация Листа для функции статического вида, где принимаются функции имеющие лишь статично 1 параметр например типа int я смог. Вопрос в следующем? Как реализовать, что бы в лист можно было вложить функции принимающие любые типы параметров и в нестатическом количестве и можно ли так сделать?

Например иметь возможность вложить 3 функции таких видов в 1 List.

```
    async Task<string> testTask() {} 
    async Task<string> testTask(int a) {} 
    async Task<string> testTask(string a, object b) {}
```

Только до такого смог додуматься,но, увы, такое очевидно не работает.

```
  List< Func< params(object),Task< string>>> _list;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, надо ответить на вопрос - как вы будете такие функции, с неизвестным заранее количеством параметров, вызывать? Ответ на этот вопрос и определяет способ хранения. А преобразовать функцию к нужному типу можно через замыкание.

Вот примеры.

```
var list = new List<Func<Task<string>>>();
list.Add(testFunc);
list.Add(() => testFunc(5));
list.Add(() => testFunc("6", "Hello, world!"));

var list = new List<Delegate>();
list.Add(new Func<Task<string>>(testFunc));
list.Add(new Func<int, Task<string>>(testFunc));
list.Add(new Func<string, string , Task<string>>(testFunc));

var list = new List<Func<object[], Task<string>>>();
list.Add(a => testFunc());
list.Add(a => testFunc((int)a[0]));
list.Add(a => testFunc((string)a[0], (string)a[1]));
```

Comment: Мне не нужно вызывать их отдельно. Всё что мне необходимо это иметь возможность вложить их в контейнер и запускать последовательно. а так же иметь возможность удалить нужную функцию или все функции такого типа. данная реализация мне подходит, но есть ли возможность как то их определнно удалять?

Comment: @BwehaaFox заведите отдельную структуру, состоящую из имени функции (строки) и делегата. Тогда искать или удалять их можно будет по имени.

Comment: @BwehaaFox или создайте для каждой функции отдельную переменную - тогда удалять их можно будет по имени этой переменной.

Comment: Спасибо. Когда писал комментарий подумывал о создании структуры. точнее листа для имен дополнительного. но стрктура думаю будет удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с делегатами не нравится?

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace list.of.delegates.test
{
    public delegate void DelegateDefinition(params Object[] arguments);

    [TestFixture]
    public class ListOfDelegatesTest
    {
        private List<DelegateDefinition> methods;
        private int counter;

        [SetUp]
        public void setUp()
        {
            this.counter = 0;
            this.methods = new List<DelegateDefinition>();
            this.methods.Add(new DelegateDefinition(IncrementCounter));
            this.methods.Add(new DelegateDefinition(AddCounter));
        }

        public void IncrementCounter(params Object[] args)
        {
            this.counter++;
        }

        public void AddCounter(params Object[] args)
        {
            int value = (int)args[0];
            this.counter += value;
        }

        [Test]
        public void execute_IncrementCounter_test()
        {
            this.methods[0]();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, this.counter);
        }

        [Test]
        public void execute_AddCounter_test()
        {
            this.methods[1](35);
            Assert.AreEqual(35, this.counter);
        }
    }
}
```